# Webpack and jquery with data annotations under internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, data-annotations, webpack-4

I am using webpack v4.18.0 and attempting to bundle `jquery`, `jquery-validation` and `jquery-validation-unobtrusive` into a single file. I have seen several suggestions on how to perform this task and most work in chrome, however I cannot get all data annotations to work in Internet Explorer 11 unless I declare the three jquery packages discretely using cdn versions.

My bundle is defined as:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
import 'jquery';
import 'jquery-validation';
import 'jquery-validation-unobtrusive';
```

Without using the `webpack.ProvidePlugin` plugin, this works with chrome. However adding it as per the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery) still doesn't help the case for IE 11. The attributes from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` v4.5.0 always fail with that browser (for example `required` is always triggered even when a value is present and `StringLength` never prevents an entry that exceeds the max).

Does anyone know what the issue with `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` under IE 11 might be?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to have been npm's default version range handling for `jquery-validation` allowing an update to v1.18.0, see [jquery-validation #2211](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/2211).